# Parse error: syntax error. What went wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, loops, syntax

I am trying to loop array from database in email.php but i am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /home/xxx/public_html
/email.php on line 62
```

This is the code in email.php:

```
$allowed_senders = Array(

  $query = "SELECT email FROM members";  // Line 62
  $result = mysql_query($query); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
  { 
    $loop_email = $row['email'];
    echo "'".$loop_email."',";   
  }    

);
```

I don't understand what went wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is *way* off:

```
  $allowed_senders = array();

  $query = "SELECT email FROM members";  // Line 62
  $result = mysql_query($query); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
  { 
    $allowed_senders[] =  $row['email'];
  }
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Works perfect!! and thanks for the tutorial John! :)